# Extremely slow random string generator

Tags: c++

I came up with the below code to generate 100001 random strings.the strings should be unique. However, the below code takes hours to do the job. Can someone let me know how i can optimize it and why is it so slow?

```
string getRandomString(int length) {     
    static string charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";   
    string result;
    result.resize(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.length()];   
    }
    return result; 
} 
void main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    vector<string> storeUnigrams;
    int numUnigram = 100001; 
    string temp = "";
    int minLen = 3;
    int maxLen = 26;
    int range = maxLen - minLen + 1;
    int i =0;

    while(i < numUnigram){
        int lenOfRanString = rand()%range   + minLen;
        temp = getRandomString(lenOfRanString);
        bool doesithave = false;
        for(int j =0 ; j < storeUnigrams.size() ; j++){
            if(temp.compare(storeUnigrams[j]) == 0){
                doesithave = true;
                break;
            }
            if(temp.compare(storeUnigrams[j]) < 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!doesithave){
            storeUnigrams.push_back(temp);
            sort(storeUnigrams.begin(),storeUnigrams.end());
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two factors that make your code slow:

1. Checking by linear search whether the string already exists – O(n)
2. Sorting the vector in each iteration – O(n log n)

Use e.g. a `set` for storing the strings – it's sorted automatically, and checking for existence is fast:

```
int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    set<string> storeUnigrams;
    int numUnigram = 100001; 
    int minLen = 3;
    int maxLen = 26;
    int range = maxLen - minLen + 1;

    while(storeUnigrams.size() < numUnigram){
        int lenOfRanString = rand()%range   + minLen;
        storeUnigrams.insert(getRandomString(lenOfRanString));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I was going to post a very similar code, so meh. But anyway, you should remove the vector and store things directly in the set. If OP just wants an ordered sequence of random strings, the std::set is the way to go.

Comment: @mfontanini: Indeed, the vector can be eliminated in this case.

Comment: @Philipp: But doesn't keeping the set sorted also have an implicit O(nlogn) cost which offsets the O(nlogn) cost used by vectors?

Comment: @Programmer: Inserting an element into a set has only O(log n) complexity. In your original algorithm, the total complexity is O(n² log n), my version has only O(n log n) (on average).

Comment: @Philipp : In my originial post, isn't the complexity O(n^2logn + n^2)?

Comment: @Programmer For large n, n^2 is small compared to n^2 log n, and so the two are equivalent. The simpler form is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Philipp answer is fine. Another approach would be to use a [Self-balancing Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) like [Red Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) instead of Vector. You can perform search and insets in log(n) time. If search is empty, insert the element.

Comment: Not the best solution since you are still sorting the whole vector during every iteration. Thus, you still have a cost of n^2logn + nlogn. Not good.

Comment: I'm not sorting whole vector. I'm inserting an element at a give index which I found using binary search. I guess it's n log n. In worst case n^2

Comment: Well in order to use bs in the first place, the vector has to be sorted. How do you maintain this

Comment: vector is always in sorted order right from 1st insert. e.g. [3], 1 comes -> [1,3], 5 comes [1,3,5], 2 comes [1,2,3,5] so on. May be C++'s vector isn't the right structure to dynamically resize like linked list, but thats the idea. Inserts are constant time.

Comment: Well, let us say the vector is sorted and you want to insert an element in the beginning of the vector. I guess c++ does this by moving all the elements to the right and then inserting. This has a huge cost (O(n)) when compared to using a set (O(logn)). Thus, not good even though you use bs

Comment: yes. I agree. As I said, vector is poor choice. But the idea is to have dynamic linked list which can be accessed like arrays. May be C++'s sets are implemented that way.

Comment: No. You don't want dynamic linked lists either. Think about inserting element at the end of the list and compare that to a set. Same case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15210/discussion-between-ankush-and-programmer)

Answer (score 0):

This code generates a unique random number only once and stores it in `random_once[i]`.

The first `for` loop generates ad stores the random number.

The second `for` loop is used to get the pre-rendered random numbers stored in the  `random_once[i]` array.

Yes generating `100001` random numbers will take hours if not days.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
      int numUnigram = 3001;
      int size=numUnigram;
      int random_once[100001];

      cout<<"Please wait: Generatng "<<numUnigram<<" random numbers   ";
      std::cout << '-' << std::flush;
      srand(time(0));



      for (int i=0;i<size;i++)  

      {

           //This code generates a unique random number only once
           //and stores it in random_once[i]

            random_once[i]=rand() % size;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++) if (random_once[j]==random_once[i]) i--; 

            //loading animation  
            std::cout << "\b\\" << std::flush;
            std::cout << "\b|" << std::flush;
            std::cout << "\b/" << std::flush;
            std::cout << "\b-" << std::flush;

      }

      cout<<" \n";

      // this code dispays unique random numbers stored in random_once[i]
      for ( i=0;i<size;i++) cout<<" "<<random_once[i]<<"\t";
      cout<<" \n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define your variables outside the while loop - because they are getting redefined at each iteration

```
int lenOfRanString = rand()%range   + minLen; ;
bool doesithave = false;
```

**Update**

Thought it's advised in many books, in practice with all the new compilers, this will not significantly improve the performance

Comment: Well sure, you want them to be. Their values change for each loop iteration. The cost of "defining" them is insignificant. This won't make any difference.

Comment: @CodyGray but isn't filling up the stack an issue on the long run ?

Comment: No, this doesn't "fill up the stack". They're automatic variables, so they go out of scope at the curly brace that ends the loop.

Comment: Best practice is to give variables the smallest scope possible, and ideally to initialise them at the point of declaration - as has been done here.

Comment: If you have a book that's recommending that, or a compiler that's not optimizing it, you need to throw both away and upgrade. :-)

Comment: Hmm, I actually don't have a copy of Code Complete 2, but you have to be careful to differentiate between variables that get reassigned each time the loop loops, and those whose values *never change*. If the values get assigned once at the beginning and then never change, then it is a useful optimization to pull them out of the loop. Sure, a good optimizing compiler will do this for you, but some might miss it. It makes good sense to do it yourself. But there's absolutely no benefit to extracting the declaration of a variable that is going to be reassigned a different value each iteration.

Comment: @CodyGray +1 ,that's a great clarification, i ll keep it in the back of my mind from now on :)

Answer (score -2):

Use char arrays instead of strings (the string class does a lot of stuff behind the scenes)

Comment: Like managing memory. You probably want that. You probably can't do a significantly better job by hand.

Comment: i was actually reffering to the [] operator that he uses quite a lot - and slows down his code quite a lot. Once the char arrays are generated he can make strings out of them for further use. The generation of the string itself should be faster with char arrays

Comment: How does the `[]` operator slow down his code? The `[]` operator doesn't even do bounds-checking for the `std::string` class (not that that should be relevant anyway).

Comment: i thought the [] operator does check for boundaries and allocates memory when needed. i  guess it doesn't

Comment: No, the `[]` operator is required to omit bounds checking precisely so that it doesn't slow down your code when you're using `std::string` like it were a character array. I'm not convinced it makes any difference, and I prefer the safety, but I didn't design the class. As far as allocating memory, yes, the `std::string` class allocates memory automatically as necessary, but there's no way for the `[]` operator to cause a memory allocation. The only thing you can access are elements that already exist. Even without bounds-checking, accessing an index that is out of range is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Gir: Show me 2 code snippets. One using char array and one using string and prove to me that the speed difference is atleast 2 times and I will be convinced that there is a cent of logic in your reasoning !!!!